# How to set permissions and ownership when using rsync?

Tags: permissions, rsync

I'm using `capistrano-wpcli` ([link](https://github.com/lavmeiker/capistrano-wpcli)), a program that uses 'rsync' to synchronize folders between development and testing servers.

I've set the `uploads` folder's permission on the remote server to 777 temporarily:

`drwxrwxrwx 3 web www-data 4096 May 24 20:04 uploads`

I'm performing rsync operation as a `deploy` user, the deploy user is in `www-data` group (if it matters at all with 777 permission).

The rsync command looks like this:

rsync -avz --rsh=ssh web/app/uploads/ deploy@domain.com:/srv/www/domain.com/shared/uploads/

Unfortunately, the rsync operation returns this error message several times:

> rsync: failed to set times on "/srv/www/domain.com/shared/uploads/.":
>   Operation not permitted (1)

Why is the rsync operation not permitted?

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/200012/rsync-failed-to-set-times-on-dir-path ?